# Is it possible to get a list of all zip codes that your driving directions pass through?

Tags: android, html, google-maps, driving-directions

I'm looking (and not finding) any reference in the google maps api (both Android and Web) to get a list of all the zip codes that a given driving path moves through.

Am I overlooking this or is this not something that the API supports?

So, to be clear, I have directions from point A to point B and I'm interested in pulling up all the unique zip codes that the path goes through (not just the zip codes of the individual points where navigation instructions are given, but ALL zip codes for the entire path).

Answer (score 1):

*Why the zip codes? of all things? The zip code in the US only represents a very small portion of an address. Also, most people don't know zip codes, a more useful piece of information would be the city/county a car is driving through. Are you from outside the United States by any chance? Or are you making an application for postal workers?*

In any case, what you're looking for is **reverse geocoding**. See this example of [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) on Google Maps.You give it a longitude and latitude and the server sends you back an address with the zip code included (for your purpose, you'll just need to disregard the rest of the information it gives you). This will have to be done on a point by point basis. There is nothing in the documentation I just linked to, that does this for an entire path.

If I were you, I'd go directly to the source, the [census bureau](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/). That's where Google Maps takes its address data from anyway.

Comment: ha ha... No, not an application for postal workers. An application for motorcyclists to give them a weather forecast along their route. I believe looking up the weather is simplest by zip code, though you're right, it may be just as easy with geo-codes... I guess it depends on the specifics of the Weather data api that I find (haven't looked into it yet). I guess as long as I can get the geocode for every 5 miles (or so) along the route, it should be a pretty straight forward proposition.

Comment: Ah ok. This weather api for instance seems to accept any of these arguments: "Pass US Zipcode, UK Postcode, Canada Postalcode, IP address, Latitude/Longitude (decimal degree) or city name" https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/page/explorer-free (I would assume that all the other weather apis would also accept Latitude/Longitude to the decimal degree)

Comment: yeah, the problem seems to be that there's no way to get coordinates for "every x meters along my route" from the google maps api.  So... getting weather data is currently a secondary concern.

Comment: Personally as a workaround, I'd just draw a straight line from my start position to my end destination (or a straight line between my known waypoints, in case the user entered them), and I'd give priority to the points that are the closest to my current position. Not a perfect solution I know, but when it comes to weather prediction, everything is an approximation anyway.

Comment: unfortunately that would not produce a meaningful result. Weather prediction is approximate, but it's not *that approximate. If I'm going from Sacramento to Salt Lake City there's a 644 mile stretch in the directions which are just one chunk that go right over the Sierras. Even without extreme accuracy, I need to know that there may be areas where the temperature will vary by 50º. Frankly I'm surprised that as sophisticated as gMaps is it doesn't have the ability to give you arbitrary points along your route!

Answer (score 1):

Zip codes tend to be irregular in their shape in size (from covering large portions of towns to just a single floor of an office block).

Google does not appear to provide a facility to get the unique zip codes that your route passes through but you could certainly try and query (reverse geocoding for a lat-long coordinate) every x meters along your route to get a (near) complete list.

When you request directions you get a directionResult object which contains many DirectionLeg objects, which contains DirectionStep objects which have a lat-lng for their path. If the lat-lngs are too far apart you can interpolate, if they are two close you can skip some.

Comment: I'm failing to find the mechanism in the docs to scan for geo-code every x meters along the route... do you happen to have a link to the instructions on how to pull this data?

Comment: @GeniaS. There is no Google mechanism for that. You would have to process the directions and create the reverse geo-coding requests yourself. Note that google has a fairly low limit on the number of reverse geo-coding requests you can make.

Comment: thanks! Do you know if perhaps a different map API provide this feature? If not, what specifically do you mean by "process the directions", I'm having a hard time imagining what such processing would consist of if I can't traverse the route in segments and grab the coordinates for each.

Comment: @GeniaS. you should be able to transverse the directions and calculate co-ordinates for approx x distance. Somebody please let me know if that is not dooable on the latest version of the API

Comment: If I'm understanding you you're proposing that I just grab the coordinates for the locations that exist along the route where directions are supplied (i.e. "left on Main Street").  Unfortunately I can't count on there being an adequate number of these points to give the user a useful weather analysis.  Consider Sacramento to Salt Lake City, there's a single 644 mile stretch that passes through the Sierras! What's the weather difference between Sac and Lake Tahoe?? Using your approach this would not be a very useful service. :-/

Comment: @GeniaS. I think you misread my proprosal. You can check the length of any given segment in the directions and break it down into whatever size segments you want (like calculate points at 50km intervals). Also this is the first time you have mentioned a "weather service". I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish but am trying my best to help you along but you do need to apply yourself a little bit. Your last response indicates to me that you are looking for somebody to just give you the answer (despite a lack of details in exactly what you are trying to do).

Comment: I'm sorry I took for granted that you read my comment in the provided answer (silly, I had no reason to think that).  I'm not at all looking for someone to give me "the" answer. There's not much here to figure out, actually. I just don't see in the apiDocs a way to get the segmented coordinates you're referring to. If you can point me at that documentation, I will ask for nothing further :-). So, if I'm misunderstanding your advice, what exactly are you proposing?

Comment: @GeniaS. I don't mean to be rude but have you even looked at the documentation? 

A quick inspection would reveal that when you request directions you get a directionResult object which contains many DirectionLeg objects, which contains DirectionStep objects which have a lat-lng for their path. If the lat-lngs are too far apart you can interpolate, if they are two close you can skip some. 

A very quick inspection of the Google API V3 documentation would reveal this. Did you try this? Did it work?
(edited answer to reflect this)

Comment: You're not being rude, but you're also not being fair. You will notice that my question starts with "I'm looking for (and not finding)...". Also you will notice that my first tag is Android. So, if your answer is that in the V3 documentation for the Javascript api, one can do what you're describing, great! thanks! I'll pursue that. But it's silly to give me a hard time for looking here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary.html and not finding what you're describing.

Comment: @GeniaS. Right you are. I didn't notice that you had put Android in your tags so apologies for giving you trouble based on the V3 API that I am used to. I'm not familiar with the Andoird API but is not possible to interpolate between segments in the directions given to get points. However, if you try that method, it might mean a huge number of round trips back and forth to the server.